# How can I effectively track my expenses?

Tags: budget, expenses, spending

How can I effectively track my expenses?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Your first paragraph is the answer to your question. I'm not sure what the point of your post is.

Comment: @littleadv My AI chatbots had given a very long list. I have taken only the relevant content.

Comment: Reposting chatbots is a sure way to get downvoted.

Comment: Is "moneybag" some sort of terminology used in a specific application? I understand the word; it's just not one you encounter in everyday conversation.

Comment: answers to this question will never help anyone else. You seem to have no idea where to start, not even that you don't know where to start. Imagine asking a friend who tracks expenses how they do it. Ask us what you would ask that friend.

Comment: I'm assuming "moneybag" is either local idiom or translation problem. Most of us would have said "wallet", or left out the "from" clause entirely.

Comment: Edit proposed to drop the chatbot text. Which makes obvious that the author hasn't actually tried to research this themselves, which is what's getting downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're being downvoted because you haven't given us enough details about what isn't working for you to offer anything but the absolutely standard description of budgeting:

Write down every purchase at the time you make it. And/or get receipts for every purchase and use those. And/or use a credit card which categorizes purchases, or where you can make a good enough guess from where the purchase occurred  Transcribe into appropriate stylesheet or home financial program.  Track the totals. Decide what you SHOULD be spending in each category such that it adds up to something you can afford. Work to control your spending to match that goal. Continue to track the totals. Repeat. Repeat. Repeat.

A few of the credit cards which do categorization will give you categorized subtotals on the statements, but that still doesn't address cash purchases or things where a single card purchase fits in several categories.

Comment: "I suspect you're being downvoted because you haven't given us enough details about what isn't working for you to offer anything but the absolutely standard description of budgeting." What else do I need to add?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing? What do you need beyond what the many websites on this topic already cover?